# Index Error: List Index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

This is my first time posting in stackoverflow, so I hope I'm doing everything right in terms of site etiquette. I am in a beginning programming class (Python), and my current assignment is to calculate the molecular weight of a compound of Carbon, Hydrogen, and Oxygen, given a user input. It can be anything from C2 to C8H19O2, and so on.

I have my code and I keep getting an error I am unfamiliar with. Essentially what I am trying to do is have the code read the input compound character by character determining if it is a molecule or not. Then, it reads the character to the right of the previous character to determine if that is a number of another compound. If it is a different compound, then the previous single compound is added to a running tally of whichever molecule it was' total. if it is a number, then it will read the next character to the right to once again determine if it is a number or character. If it is a number, it multiplies the previous character number by 10 and then adds the next one, and so on, until it reaches the next character(C123H2 would be 10*1 + 2 followed by 10*12 + 3, and then it would add 123 Carbons to the running tally). Once our runny tallies are complete, then that number is multiplied by the molecular weight of one of each. I keep getting an index error that says my list index is out of range. Any help is greatly appreciated!

def main():

```
C1 = 0
H1 = 0
O1 = 0
num = 0

chemicalFormula = (input("Enter the chemical formula, or enter key to quit: "))
while True:
    cformula = list(chemicalFormula)
    for index, x in enumerate(cformula):
        if x == 'C':
            if cformula[index + 1] == 'H' or cformula[index + 1] == 'O':
                C1 += 1
            else:
                for index, y in enumerate(range(index + 1, 1000000000)):
                    if cformula[index + 1] != 'H' or cformula[index + 1] != 'O':
                        num = int(y)
                        num = num*10 + int(cformula[index + 1])
                    else:
                        C1 += num
                        break
        elif x == 'H':
            if cformula[index + 1] == 'C' or cformula[index + 1] == 'O':
                H1 += 1
            else:
                for y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
                    if cformula[index + 1] != 'C' or cformula[index + 1] != 'O':
                        num = int(y)
                        num = num*10 + cformula[index + 1]
                    else:
                        H1 += num
                        break
        elif x == 'O':
            if cformula[index + 1] == 'C' or cformula[index + 1] == 'H':
                O1 += 1
            else:
                for y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
                    if cformula[index + 1] != 'C' or cformula[index + 1] != 'H':
                        num = int(y)
                        num = num*10 + cformula[index + 1]
                    else:
                        O1 += num
                        break
        else:
            break

weightC = 15.994*C1
weightH = 1.0079*H1
weightO = 12.011*O1

sumWeight = weightC + weightH + weightO
print("The molecular weight is ", sumWeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several different variables named `index`, which are hiding each other.

First, you are iterating over cformula:

```
for index, x in enumerate(cformula)
```

OK. so `index` is always inside the sensible range for `cformula`. but right after that you do

```
for index, y in enumerate(range(index + 1, 1000000000))
```

now index can be 1000000000, and then:

```
if cformula[index + 1]
```

Oops. `cformula` is not even close to be of size 1000000002, as it needs for this expression to evaluate sensibly. I believe you don't really need `enumerate` here.

All you have to do is to access `cformula` using `x` - the current element in the main iteration. as long is you are only reading it (which is what you actually need), it will be fine.

From the question it seems you do not understand what exactly `enumerate` means - you are using it where you don't actually need anything special.

*Don't* use the same variable to mean different things!

Comment: okay, I will do some tinkering and see what I come up with! I appreciate the quick response

Comment: I was working with a friend who told me to use enumerate, not too sure what it means either to be honest haha. I'm really new with Python and our teacher assigned this program which is extremely hard and has nothing to do with anything we have studied so far so I'm in uncharted territory here.

Comment: @YotamKasznik You use `range` if you need the index, you use plain iterable (such as a list) if you only need the values. You use `enumerate` if you need both.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the approach looks pretty good for a beginner, thumbs up! Now, to answer your question from the title, the error comes from accessing an element of a sequence that doesn't exist, like e.g. the fifth element of a sequence of four elements. In your case, I guess this is triggered by the `cformula[index + 1]`, where the index could already be that of the last element. Note that it would also be interesting to know which input triggered this error, my guess is "CO" or "C2H5OH", because both have a compound letter not followed by a numer at the end.

Now, how to get around it? A very simple approach is to simply take the rest of the string (which can be empty) and handle its content.

```
count = ''
for d in cformula[index + 1:]:
    if d.isdigit():
        count += d
    else:
        break
```

This code store all digits after `cformula[index]` up to the next non-digit. If there are no digits, it store an empty string. Note that this doesn't even care which atom (C, H, O) you are looking at, so it is a good example for code that you could move to a separate function. Then, after calling that function, you check the string of digits:

```
if count == '':
    # number of atoms is implicitly 1
    atoms = 1
else:
    # number of atoms is explicitly given
    atoms = int(count)
# TODO: discard len(count) elements from the input string
```

BTW: There is a `dict` type which you could use to store the number of atoms for each element. Similarly, you could use it to store the weight of each atom type:

```
atom_weight = {'C': 15.994,
               'H': 1.0079,
               'O': 12.011,}

weight = atom_weight['C'] * C1 + atom_weight['H'] * H1 + atom_weight['O'] * O1
```

This doesn't make your code correct, but makes it easier to extend that to the rest of the periodic table. :)